# How to use HAVING Clause With SUM() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, having

I have a table with `Username` and `SummedHourCount` columns. My goal is to select the username where (`SummedHourCount / SUM(SummedHourCount)) > 3/4`. `SUM(SummedHourCount)` meaning all of the hours present in the column.

For example, if I have the following data:

| Username | SummedHourCount |
| --- | --- |
| randy.jackson | 13 |
| jaren.neilson | 1 |
| jerome.nettles | 2 |
| billy.bobjr | 1 |

I want The query to select only `randy.jackson, 13`.

The part I'm having difficulty with is implementing the HAVING clause.  I'm not incredibly familiar, but each try fails due to syntax errors, or simply doesn't work as intended and returns all results.

This is what I have currently:

```
SELECT  ValueOne, 
        SummedHourCount 
FROM
(
    SELECT  ValueOne, 
            SUM(HourCount) AS SummedHourCount 
    FROM    #loggedhours 
    GROUP BY ValueOne
) ta
GROUP BY ValueOne, SummedHourCount
HAVING (SummedHourCount / SUM(SummedHourCount)) > 3/4
```

It does nothing but return all results, but at least does not throw any syntax errors.  If someone is more knowledgeable of HAVING clauses and has some insights as to how I would structure the query, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `TOP(25) PERCENT`

Comment: It doesn't work because the SUM(SummedHourCount) in your HAVING clause refers only to the SummedHourCount for that particular value of ValueOne, so SummedHourCount/SUM(SummedHourCount) always equals 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below:

```
select username, SummedHourCount from #loggedhours cross join
(select sum(SummedHourCount) totalHours from #loggedhours) as t
where (SummedHourCount*1.0/totalHours) > 3.0/4
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to retrieve the rows that are in the top quartile of the data, may I suggest:

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT ValueOne, SummedHourCount
FROM (
    SELECT  ValueOne, 
            SUM(HourCount) AS SummedHourCount 
    FROM    #loggedhours 
    GROUP BY ValueOne
) ta
Order by SummedHourCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to find users whose hours are more than 3/4 (75%) of the total. Is that correct? If so then the following might work for you (it uses aggregation and window functions, doesn't use `HAVING` however):

```
SELECT ValueOne, SummedHourCount FROM (
    SELECT ValueOne, SummedHourCount
         , SUM(SummedHourCount) OVER () AS TotalHourCount
      FROM (
        SELECT ValueOne, SUM(HourCount) AS SummedHourCount 
          FROM #loggedhours 
         GROUP BY ValueOne
    )
) WHERE SummedHourCount / TotalHourCount > 3/4
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No `HAVING` needed. In fact, most of the other answers are also WAAAAAY too complicated.

```
SELECT *
FROM #loggedhours 
WHERE SummedHourCount > (SELECT 0.75 * SUM(SummedHourCount) FROM #loggedhours)
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/0n66jsCT